# Can computed properties have multiple properties on the setter

Tags: swift, properties

I'm very new to swift and have been having a hard time figuring out computed properties. Is there a way to pass in multiple properties to a setter or are you limited to just one? I'm attempting the following code but receive this error `Expected '{' to start setter definition` and `Expected '}' after setter parameter name`

I'm confused as to the whole type defining in swift also and have tried passing a dictionary into the setter but that then causes issues with my return type.

The code I currently have:

```
struct Shape {
    var height: Int = 0
    var width: Int = 0

    var area: Int {
        set (width, height) {
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
        }

        get {
            return self.width * self.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they can, but then you have to declare the property as `(Int, Int)`. In any case the type of the setter/getter **must** match the type of the property.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit better? How would I pass in those values to the setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass multiple values to a setter you have to declare the type of the property accordingly, for example

```
struct Shape {
   var height: Int = 0
   var width: Int = 0

   var area: (Int, Int) {
      set  {
         self.width = newValue.0
         self.height = newValue.1
      }

      get {
         return (width, height)
      }
   }
}

var shape = Shape()
shape.area = (120, 60)

print(shape.area) // (120, 60)
```

As mentioned in the comment the type of the property, setter and getter must be the same.

Comment: From what I'm getting here it would probably be a better idea to use a function to set the area without the use of stored properties?